# Problems changing dynamic url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im having problems changing this string:

```
https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/2019-04-29/
```

So when the user click, it redirect to:

```
https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=2019-04-29
```

So the variable part is:

OLD URL:

```
https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/VARIABLE_STRING/
```

NEW URL:

```
https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=VARIABLE_STRING
```

.

I tried with that:

```
RewriteRule ^agenda/([^/]*)$ agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=$1 [L]
```

And that:

```
RewriteRule ^agenda\/(.*)\/$ /agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=$1 [L]
```

But didn't worked.

PD: It's only must be the DATE VARIABLE STRING (year-month-day), because any variable string will cause problems, because there are other strings like `https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/concurso-de-fotografia-afe/` that I don't want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

`([^/]*)$` wont match because it wants "everything that is not (`^`) a slash `/`, up to the last character `$` and since that url has a slash at the end, it discards the whole match. That second one should have worked, but wouldn't be specific about what it accepts.

The rewrite rule you might be looking for is

```
RewriteRule ^agenda/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/$ agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=$1 [L]
```

This matches `agenda/2019-04-29/` but not `agenda/concurso-de-fotografia-afe/`.

Comment: I don't know what u mean with "Adjust the 4, 2, and 2 to your specific date stamp.". Date  is variable, is each day of each month. I tried your code copy and pasted but didn't worked, sorry. You can see live here: https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/2019-05-03/

Comment: Disregard the adjustment part. If you want the slash to be optional use `/?$` at the end.

Comment: I have that: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^agenda/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/?$ agenda/foto/?tribe-bar-date=$1 [L]

</IfModule>  Didn't worked: https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/2019-05-03/ Maybe it must be a redirect instead rewrite? If I changed to Redirect 301 instead RewriteRule it shows internal error.